# Dynamic changing PID - nohup process not killable - Linux

Tags: kill, nohup

I have started a [python script](https://github.com/sibalzer/impfbot/blob/main/src/impfbot.py) by following:

```
nohup python src/myscript.py &
```

Now there is a process running, where the PID is changing constantly, so it is absolutely not possible to kill it. When I try this one [nohup process killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process), it says the `-sh: kill: (8792) - No such process`.

Also tried to `grep` it by name and kill it, same issue, because the PID is changing constantly. As noted by @MarcusMüller in a comment, apparently this is because it constantly spawns new browser instances.

Really confused why nothing is working, restart did not work. Considering to reinstall whole system ...

Comment: `nohup` doesn't change PIDs (try with `nohup sleep 600`). In fact, it's impossible to change PIDs at runtime as process. more likely, your script is `forking`/spawing a lot of subprocesses. What specifically does `myscript.py` do?

Comment: How are you starting the program after rebooting?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I am not starting the Program after reboot, it is still there...

Comment: Have you tried the `killall` command, specifying the process command line as shown in `top` et al...

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://github.com/sibalzer/impfbot/blob/main/src/impfbot.py this is the Script, I cannot find something suspicious.

Comment: @JeremyBoden I tried killall, which did not help. Can you show me your command so I can try it out again?

Comment: impfbot continuously spawns new browsers. Of course you get new PIDs that way.

Comment: @csnewb if you are trying to catch PID with something like `ps | grep mask` it might be that filter returns grep's PID as well which is already gone by moment you execute `kill`. Thus the error. To avoid case like that, you might want to use `ps | grep '[m]ask'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the process command appears like `'python src/myscript.py'` in process listings such as `ps, top, htop` etc:-

`killall -s STOP 'python src/myscript.py'` would pause the processes;
-s CONT would resume them,

To see all signals, `killall -l`, but sending TERM should terminate them - and ABRT should forcibly remove them.